# How to call phtml file from custom theme to cms block

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml

I have created a custom block using Magento 2 UI, I know that I can't have any PHP in the block so I have created a `test.phtml` file and added it to my **custom** theme on the server.

Now, I want to call that block but can't figure out what path it will be.

The location of the `test.phtml` is following:

```
app/design/frontend/CustomTheme/CustomChild/Custom_Themesettings/templates/html/test.phtml
```

How should I call this `test.phtml` file in my block? I got something like this but it's not working:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="app/design/frontend/CustomTheme/CustomChild/Custom_Themesettings/templates/html/test.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

File location will be

```
app/design/frontend/CustomTheme/CustomChild/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml
```

calling a block

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testblock" template="html/test.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean a static block in the admin? If so try this:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Custom_Themesettings::html/test.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why `Custom_Themesettings`? if you want to add it in your **theme** use :  `app/design/frontend/{package}/{themename}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/test.phtml`, if you have created a custom **module** put it : `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/view/frontend/templates/html/test.phtml`

To call the **theme** one :

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/test.phtml"}}
```

the **module** one :

```
{{block class="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Block\{Blockname.php}" template="Vendor_Modulename::html/test.phtml"}}
```